# Migrating docker images to a custom registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I need to migrate a bunch of images from a docker hub account to a custom registry on-premises.
However, those images are used and referenced by many other docker files and docker-compose files.

So here's the problem. Let's say, I've got an image called foo, then if I migrate it to a docker registry at bar:5000, I need to change its tag to bar:5000/foo, but docker files and docker compose files that use it still reference it as just "foo", and will not be able to pull it once it is removed from docker hub. Changing the tags in every reference (and searching for each reference) feels like an overkill - it will take a load of time and in case the host of the custom registry changes, changing the tags in each reference will have to be performed again.

Is there any way to keep the naming of the images in the references (so that the names look as in docker hub) and actually store the images in a custom repository?

I tried using the docker hub account name as the host name for the custom registry, but without a port it still tries to pull from docker hub instead of the custom registry.

I tried configuring the mirror registry, but even with it configured when I push an image, docker attempts to push it to docker hub instead.

What else can I do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Add the private registry endpoints in the daemon.json file

```
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
  "insecure-registries" : ["IP_OF_YOUR_REGISTRY:5000"]
}
```

Restart the docker service

```
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The choices that I can think of are:

1. Update everything to point to the new registry location
2. Configure a mirror in your runtime and build tooling
3. MitM all network requests to Hub to force them to your local registry

Option 2 is error prone since docker only treats the mirror for pulling images, and automatically/silently falls back to Hub on errors, so you need to update all of the push commands to point to the new registry.

Option 3 requires that you update your build tooling and runtimes to trust a MitM that is impersonating Docker Hub.

Option 1 is typically the easiest option. For a large project, you typically break this up into smaller chunks (teams, groups, projects, or even individual image builds). And during that transition, you keep the base images mirrored between the two registries.